# How anything will be decided as because of bad karma or good karma?

Tags: karma

Assume there are two persons and both are destined to loss their money and should become beggers.

One of them has weak mentality and he was not able to bear and he became sad and is completely disappointed.

Other person is opposite and is a sportive person and he did not even think of it as bad luck and just enjoyed his life.

Does that mean only first person consumed his karma or both? If a person strongly behaves that he can forget his bad luck, then how Karma will become basis for Hinduism?

Comment: I don't think Karma has anything to do with how a person deals with it emotionally. A person's karma is defined by their actions (be it good or bad) and they get the fruit of it, either in this life or in another life. In your example, both were put in such situations due to their karma for xyz reasons. Their emotional/mental reaction to the situation has nothing to do with karma.

Comment: What is meant by bad karma, if a person kills someone that hurts that person so he attained bad karma, but if karma does not take one's emotions then it cant be defined as bad or good karma i.e. there is no guarantee that bad karma causes bad luck only and good karma causes good luck only. Every action has a reaction whether it is good or bad

Comment: See whatever actions you take in a situation are your karma. If you killed a person's child because of some reason, then that's bad karma. That same pain will be returned to you one day. If you do charity/care for your family/be a righteous person etc, then these are good deeds. Doing good karma (actions that don't harm anyone) without expectations for getting fruit of it, will release you from this endless cycle of birth and death. Think of Karma as debts to be paid to people you did good/bad to

Comment: how an individual's karma is meted out is known by only the Lord. What appears to you to be the same may not be the same at all.